# Compute the greater common divisor & the smallest common multiple of N numbers

Tags: code-golf

Your mission is to write 2 functions that accept a list of N integers (positive or negative).

N can be higher than 2.

The first one returns the greater common divisor of the N numbers

**Example**: [10, 15, 20] -> 5

the second one returns the smallest common multiple of the N numbers

**Example**: [10, 15, 20] => 60

Smallest code (in number of characters) wins!

Comment: If you're going to require support for negative integers in the input, you need to make clear how you're defining LCM and give relevant test cases.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruby 38 characters

```
g=->a{a.inject:gcd}
l=->a{a.inject:lcm}
```

demo:

```
ar = [10,15,20]
p g[ar] #=> 5
p l[ar] #=> 60
```

Answer (score 0):

### J, 12 characters

```
g=.+./
l=.*./
```

A bit pointless giving them aliases like this really.

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk (Smalltalk/X) (73 chars)

```
a:=#(10 15 20). 
g:=a fold:[:i :e|i gcd:e].   
l:=a fold:[:i :e|i lcm:e].
```

without fold: (Ansi Smalltalk), use (102 chars):

```
a := #(10 15 20).
g := a inject:a first into:[:i :e | i gcd:e].   
l := a inject:a first into:[:i :e | i lcm:e].
```